# Y_train values for symbolicRegressor

Tags: python-3.x, genetic, gplearn

I split my dataset in `X_train`, `Y_train`, `X_test` and `Y_test`, and then I used the symbolicRegressor...

I've already convert the string values from Dataframe in float values.
But by applying the `symbolicRegressor` I get this error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'd'

Where 'd' is a value from Y.

Since all my values in `Y_train` and `Y_test` are alphabetic character because they are the "labels", I can not understand why the `symbolicRegressor` tries to get a float number ..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `https://gplearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html` - "Symbolic regression is a machine learning technique that aims to identify an underlying mathematical expression that best describes a relationship". Pay attention to `mathematical`. I am not good at the topic of the question and `gplearn`'s description does not clearly define area of applicability / restrictions.

However, according to the source code `https://gplearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/gplearn/genetic.html` method `fit()` of `BaseSymbolic` class contains line `X, y = check_X_y(X, y, y_numeric=True)` where `check_X_y()` is `sklearn.utils.validation.check_X_y()`. Argument `y_numeris` means: "Whether to ensure that y has a numeric type. If dtype of y is object, it is converted to float64. Should only be used for regression algorithms".

So `y` values must be numeric.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems that I don't check the meaning of X_train and Y_train... since I thought that:                                                                                            X_train is the training data set and Y_train is the "set of labels to all the data in X_train", that's why my Y_train consist of names or (in this case) alphabetic characters....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late replay. `gplearn` supports regression (numeric y) with the `SymbolicRegressor` estimator, and with the newly released `gplearn 0.4.0` we also support binary classification (two labels in y) using the `SymbolicClassifier`. From the sounds of things though, you have a multi-label problem which `gplearn` does not currently support. It may be something we look to support in the future.